# How can download file in service in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-download-manager

I want **download** file from `server` and i want download this in background such as service.

My codes is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button download;
    TextView downloadCount;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    Future<File> downloading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Enable global Ion logging
        Ion.getDefault(this).configure().setLogging("ion-sample", Log.DEBUG);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
        downloadCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.download_count);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        final File file = new File(dir, "filename.zip");

        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (downloading != null && !downloading.isCancelled()) {
                    resetDownload();
                    return;
                }

                download.setText("Cancel");
                // this is a 180MB zip file to test with
                downloading = Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load("http://cdn.p30download.com/?b=p30dl-software&f=PCWinSoft.1AVMonitor.v1.9.1.50_p30download.com.rar")
                        // attach the percentage report to a progress bar.
                        // can also attach to a ProgressDialog with progressDialog.
                        .progressBar(progressBar)
                        // callbacks on progress can happen on the UI thread
                        // via progressHandler. This is useful if you need to update a TextView.
                        // Updates to TextViews MUST happen on the UI thread.
                        .progressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                                downloadCount.setText("" + downloaded + " / " + total);
                            }
                        })
                        // write to a file
                        .write(file)
                        // run a callback on completion
                        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Exception e, File result) {
                                resetDownload();
                                if (e != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error downloading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File upload complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    void resetDownload() {
        // cancel any pending download
        downloading.cancel();
        downloading = null;

        // reset the ui
        download.setText("Download");
        downloadCount.setText(null);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

i write above codes but i don't know how can i write this code into `service` and download file in **background**.

How can i write this codes in service?

Answer (score 0):

A service can be started using `context.startService(intent)` .
Once the service is started, it's lifecycle is executed as below (in sequence):

1. `onCreate()`
2. `onStartCommand()`

When the service is stopped or destroyed, it's `onDestroy()` method is called.

Now to download the file in service, call the `startService()` method as below (From your activity in this case):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceName.class);
startService(intent);
```

This will start the service. Now to start the download process, call your `downloadFile()` method as show below:

```
public class ServiceName extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Start download process
        downloadFile();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return 
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void downloadFile() {
        //Logic to download the file.
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Also you can bind the `service` to the `activity` to pass callbacks between them and *bind* the service w/ activity's lifecycle. Checkout this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for more info on this.

Comment: Also, as a note, remember you have to account for multi-threading with Services, as opposed to Intent-Service which takes care of that for you. However, you're intents will be queued up if using an Intent-Service, because they execute one after the other. Just see what works for you..

Comment: onStartCommand need to return START_REDELIVER_INTENT , if serive gets killed you want it to always get restarted and continue from where it had stopped.